# Trying To Delay the Appearance of JLabels in a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay, jlabel

Hi I've there a little problem: What I want is to delay the appearance of `JLabels` in a `JDialog-Window`, in terms of that the first line of `JLabels` shoud come out and then two seconds later the second line of `Jlabels` etc.
I've tried something with `Windowlistener`,the `doClick()`-Method etc., bu every time the `Jdialog` revalidates all of its panels AT ONCE and shows them without any delaying!

Please help me(Just copy the code below and try out)!

```
package footballQuestioner;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class attempter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JDialog dialog = new Punkte();
    }

}

class Punkte extends JDialog {

    private JPanel screenPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    private int i = 1;

    private class WindowHandler implements WindowListener {

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            button.doClick(1000);
            button.doClick(1000);
            button.doClick(1000);
            button.doClick(); // here im trying to delay the appearance of the
                                // JLabels....
        }

    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (i) {

            case 1:
                settingUpPanel(getPanelFromScreenPanel(i), "Right", new Color(
                        102, 205, 0));
                settingUpPanel(getPanelFromScreenPanel(i), "Wrong", Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2:
                settingUpPanel(getPanelFromScreenPanel(i), "Trefferquote",
                        Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case 3:
                settingUpPanel(getPanelFromScreenPanel(i), "Ausgezeichnet",
                        Color.BLUE);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;

        }
    }

    public Punkte() {

        button.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        addWindowListener(new WindowHandler());

        setModal(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        settingUpScreenPanel();

        add(screenPanel);

        setSize(1200, 1000);
        centeringWindow();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void settingUpScreenPanel() {

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel rightWrongCountPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        JPanel shareOfRightQuestions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel grade = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        settingUpPanel(titlePanel, "Result", Color.BLACK);

        // settingUpPanel(rightWrongCountPanel,
        // "Right: "+numberOfRightAnsers+"/6",new Color(102,205,0));
        // settingUpPanel(rightWrongCountPanel,
        // "Wrong: "+(6-numberOfRightAnsers)+"/6", Color.RED);
        // settingUpPanel(shareOfRightQuestions,
        // "Trefferquote: "+(numberOfRightAnsers*100/6)+"%",Color.YELLOW);
        // settingUpPanel(summaSummarum,
        // getBufferedImage("footballQuestioner/Strich.png"));
        // settingUpPanel(grade,"Aushezeichnet", Color.BLUE);

        borderingJPanel(screenPanel, null, null);

        titlePanel.setOpaque(false);
        rightWrongCountPanel.setOpaque(false);
        shareOfRightQuestions.setOpaque(false);
        grade.setOpaque(false);

        screenPanel.add(titlePanel);
        screenPanel.add(rightWrongCountPanel);
        screenPanel.add(shareOfRightQuestions);
        screenPanel.add(grade);

    }

    private void settingUpPanel(JComponent panel, String string, Color color) {

        Font font = new Font("Rockwell Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 65);
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel(string);

        label.setForeground(color);
        label.setFont(font);

        innerPanel.add(label);
        innerPanel.setOpaque(false);

        panel.add(innerPanel);

        panel.validate();
        panel.repaint();

    }

    public JPanel getPanelFromScreenPanel(int numberOfPanel) {

        JPanel screenPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane().getComponent(0);
        JPanel labelPanel = (JPanel) screenPanel.getComponent(numberOfPanel);

        return labelPanel;
    }

    public void centeringWindow() {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x;
        int y;

        x = (int) (dimension.getWidth() - getWidth()) / 2;
        y = (int) (dimension.getHeight() - getHeight()) / 2;

        setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public void borderingJPanel(JComponent panel, String jPanelname,
            String fontStyle) {

        Font font = new Font(fontStyle, Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12);

        if (jPanelname != null) {
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.GRAY,
                            Color.WHITE), jPanelname,
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, font));
        } else if (jPanelname == null || fontStyle == null) {
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.BLACK,
                            Color.WHITE)));
        }

        panel.setOpaque(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can't you filter out the unimportant parts?

Comment: Consider using `CardLayout` and Swing `Timer`.

Comment: one moment please ....

Comment: Try defining all of the JLabels at one time with one space, then use a Runnable or Swing Timer to set the text in the JLabels.

Comment: much shorter code! :-))))

Comment: YEEEAAAHHHH! With the help of timer the code does function!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really good use case for `javax.swing.Timer`...

This will allow you to schedule a callback, at a regular interval with which you can perform an action, safely on the UI.

```
private class WindowHandler extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("...");
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel panel = getPanelFromScreenPanel(1);
                panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

                for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                    panel.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(index)), gbc);
                }
                panel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

}
```

Now, if you wanted to do a series of actions, separated by the interval, you could use a `counter` to determine the number of "ticks" that have occurred and take appropriate action...

```
private class WindowHandler extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("...");
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            private int counter = 0;
            private int maxActions = 10;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switch (counter) {
                    case 0:
                        // Action for case 0...
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // Action for case 1...
                        break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }
                counter++;
                if (counter >= maxActions) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details